# Unable to use ES6 string in the require syntax

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Hi i am just looking into react there i am using ecmascript-6 in mine code i am requiring image files from mine static folder. For that i am using the code as posted below.

```
const config.staticAssetBasePath = './../../../static/assets/';
const mapIcon = require(`${config.staticAssetBasePath}icon/map_grey.png`);
```

But when i run than i am getting as error unable to require '.'

So please let me know the problem with mine syntax that throwing me error in the browser console.

Comment: `const config.staticAssetBasePath = ` is invalid syntax

Comment: In actual i m including a config file as import config from 'config';

Comment: so even if i use const staticAssetPath = './../../../static/asset/'; than also it does not work @RGraham

Comment: maybe the problem is that the path you are including is starting with one dot? Try two, '../' etc

Comment: tried with that by romoving one dot still getting the error Cannot find module "."(…) @alynioke